Access Named Credentials with Guest User
I have created a Rest Service which accepts incoming Webhooks from Concur to notify Salesforce an Expense Report is ready.  I am then using a Callout Class to fetch the Expense Report details from Concur and insert them in Salesforce
I cannot include authentication details in the Webhook so the incoming requests are orginating from from the Site's Guest user.
Initially I built the Callout Class using hardcoded values for the credentials - Password & Client Secret. I was able to send a Webhook, fetch the details and create the records.
I wanted to harden the process so I moved the sensitive information to a Named Credential with the Keys and Password assigned to Principals in the External Credential. This works when I execute it locally with my user, but not when I submit a Webhook. In the debug log i receive the error "You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "ConcurNC""
I confirmed the Guest User Profile is assigned to External Credential, has API access and Access to all of the Apex Classes.
Based on the documentation this should be all that is required.
Is there a way to Change Default Guest User on the site?
Is there a permission I am missing?

does guest user permissions include  CRUD access to object UserExternalCredentials ?

THANK YOU!  I did not even realize that was an Object.  I enabled Create and Read and now the Guest User has access!

Based on the response from  @cropredy I enabled Create and Read Permissons for the User External Credentials Object and the Guest User can now access the Named Credential!


The answer above might work for maybe another SF user type, but def doesnt work for a Guest User profile.
